# When arrested in the Shrine of Talos during "The Forsworn Conspiracy" do you lose your current attributes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I get the recent murders pinned on me by the Marcarth guards, will my health, magika and stamina be reset?

Answer (score 3):

No, you will not lose your current attributes.

However:

> You will temporarily lose your equipment.

Comment: Lol thanks but in the future it may be best to put the spoiler alert BEFORE the actual spoiler. O_O

Comment: You asked for it. I only tried to spare you a spoiler further down the mission.